# 406-Not Acceptable Response - jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, http-status-code-406

I am receiving the 406 error when I am sending a JSON data object through the jQuery AJAX function to a backend service so the data can be stored into the database.

**AJAX FUNCTION**

```
data = {
  questions: questions,
  test_id: test_id,
  action: 'update'
};

gmtjax({
    url: gmt.contextPath + 'tests/questions/process_form',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    $spinner: gmt.$spinnerContainer,
    success: function(returnData) {
      console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(){
      //console.log('error');
    },
    $errorContainer: gmt.$mainContainer
});
```

**JSON structure:**

```
{
    "test_id": "1",
    "action": "update",
    "questions": [
        {
            "question": "Exploitation strategies seek to create value from unfamiliar resources and activities.",
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "True"
                },
                {
                    "name": "False"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Process Form Function (Backend)**

```
function process_form(){
  print_r($_POST);
}
```

---

When I submit the data the STATUS CODE on the XHR request is 406 Not Acceptable.

**Request Header**

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,af;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1726
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:ci_session=08c62699d06dfcf8ba853cacb350ab3b
Host:testingsite.com
Origin:https://testingsite.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:https://testingsite.com/tests/manage/id/194/goto/2
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

**RESPONSE**

```
false
```

When the request fails it does not even enter the process_form function to print out the POST array.

---

However, when I modify the 'create value' string in the question to something like 'create ***a*** value' the form submits successfully.  The only thing I can think of is some SQL Injection prevention detection on the server layer (GoDaddy) but I am unsure on how to address this.

What could be causing the 406 error when Content-Type is obviously not the issue.

Comment: you have to first pinpoint what the problem is. Either your json is sometimes malformed or doesn't contain what the backend requires, or there's something wrong with the backend.

Comment: Can you share the code that is firing the AJAX request and the code that is processing on the back end as well?

Comment: did you try to remove the dataType: 'json' and submit anything else just to check if it works? That way you can be sure if its the json or another thing.

Comment: Does `process_form` get called `process_form()` ?

Comment: @guest271314 - That is web service so the process_form() is called based on the URL.

Comment: @12Bo Does `data` get stored at db ? At Question , `success` callback appear to be `console.log("success")` ? Does `console` return `"success"` ? Is requirement to return results of `print_r()` to `console` at `success` callback ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be caused by a module called `mod_security` and it can cause this problem. Your code looks fine to me. So, check out your host, see if `mod_security` is installed and enabled, and if it is, try disabling it temporarily and then test this code again. If `mod_security` is not the culprit, don't forget to re-enable it.

Comment: I am working with GoDaddy to see if they can disable this setting.  More information to come.

Comment: what should i do if my server does not allow disabling of such mod? such as hostgator

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are sending post data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, while your service probably requires `application/json`. Try sending actual JSON:

```
gmtjax({
    url: gmt.contextPath + 'tests/questions/process_form',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    $spinner: gmt.$spinnerContainer,
    success: function(returnData) {
      console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(){
      //console.log('error');
    },
    $errorContainer: gmt.$mainContainer
});
```

Comment: Are you using any particular frameworks on the PHP site? What's the call stack that should lead to `process_form()`? What are the new request headers and full response headers? (please update the question with this info)

Answer (score 1):

Try

at close of php at process form page

```
echo print_r($_POST);
```

at `success` callback

```
console.log(returnData);
```

if request , response successful , should return

```
Array
(
    [test_id] => 1
    [action] => update
    [questions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [question] => Exploitation strategies seek to create value from unfamiliar resources and activities.
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => True
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => False
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
1
```

at `error` callback

```
error : function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, jqxhr.getAllResponseHeaders()
             , errorThrown)
}
```

at `ajaxSetup`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   statusCode : {
            200 : function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                    console.log(data);
            },
            406 : function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
            }
        }
 });
```

try log both `200` success , `406` statusCode error.

Answer (score 1):

406 Not Acceptable error using jQuery AJAX
It turned out the problem was that I was submitting the ajax request using the POST
method but not actually sending any post data. For example:

```
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "index.php?action=foo",
   success: function(msg){
 
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms that you're describing are characteristic of a web application firewall put in place by your web host. Contact their support department.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type of AJAX call to GET from POST type. It might help you.

Comment: This wouldn't be possible because the number of questions could by dynamic and don't want to worry about hitting the URL character limit.

Answer (score 0):

May be a header issue. Try adding this to your `$.ajax()`:

```
headers: { 
    Accept : "application/json"
}
```